# document.ready and iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My page loads an iframe. 
The iframe contains a small markup, including " Click  "

I have a js file, included it controls a click-event for the buton.
Currently the JS file is included, in the small page, which my iframe loads.

I want to include my javascript library on the containing page level, not in the page which the iframe loads.  So , I moved it. Those of you who know your stuff, will not be surprised to hear
that when I did this, the click() event stopped firing.

```
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                          $('#filter_button').click(function(){
                                    //operations
                            });

                    });
```

I loosely understand, that it is because the .ready function is traversing the DOM before the iframe loads... but I don't know what to do about it.  Any help?

Comment: An iframe has a different window context. It sounds like you understand the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which is good. Unfortunately jQuery isn't designed to work across window contexts; getting a listener to fire when the iframe hits `document.ready` is much more involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the jQuery load() method with a callback to wire up the events on your loaded page after it has finished loading.

Replacing path_to_page.html with your current iframe url:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadedContent').load('path_to_page.html', function() {
        $('#filter_button').click(function(){ 
        //operations 
        }); 
    });
});
```

Replace your iframe with this:

```
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that, I would have not thought of that myself. But, i went ahead and pre-hypertext processed the iframe.  I am working in PHP after all. I think I was leaving too much up to chance, in the browser.  I just replaced the iframe with a php "include once"

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sure that all content is loaded, images, iframes etc. (not just the DOM being ready) before you run your code, you can make use of jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of `$(document).ready(function(){});`:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

Comment: Should have mentioned in the first post, I've already tried window.load() same problem.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: There is no `window.load()`, only $(window).load() and `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

I did this in on my main page where iframe attr() is set:

```
$("#my_iframe") .attr( "src", template ) // template is the iframe content path
                .one( "load", function() {

                    $("#my_iframe")[0].contentWindow.$('body').trigger('contentReady');

                } ).each( function() {
                    if( this.complete ) //trigger load if cached in certain browsers
                        $(this).trigger("load");
                } );
```

and then put my code in the iframe this way:

```
$(window).on( "contentReady", function(e) {
    // code I usually initiate with document ready
} );
```

I am not a javascript expert. The attr()…on.("load"…  technique I learned from someone else in relation to exchange an image. So I combined it here with my iframe script.